# referencing an object using auto iterator

Tags: c++

```
unordered_map<char,int> letter;

for (auto it = letter.begin(); it != letter.end() ; it++) {
    if (it->second) return false;    
}

for (auto it : letter) {
    if (it.second) return false;
}
```

Above, there are 2 iterator loops which I believe output the same thing. I can understand that the `it` in the first loop points to the object in the `unordered_map`, so the second variable must be referenced with `->`. But I dont understand how the second loop can do `.second`. Can anyone explain how to 2nd loop works?

Comment: it in the second loop `it`is not an iterator, but a `pair`

Answer (score 4):

The second loop is a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). It is not returning an iterator, but is instead returning a copy of the key-value pair (`pair<char, int>`), so it does not need to ues a `->` operator to access the values.

Your range-based for would be equivalent to this, only less verbose, of course.

```
for (auto it = letter.begin(); it != letter.end() ; it++) {
    auto kvp = *it;
    if (kvp.second) return false;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `auto&& it : letter` to get references rather than copies.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the explanation. Since I am also new to **unordered_map** I don't fully understand it yet. To be clear, unordered maps use **pair<first, second> where you can declare the types of variables. correct?